# Idera ServerBackup / R1soft Kernel Modules

Tags: linux, backup, kernel, r1soft

We currently have virtual (xen) servers from a host here in the UK and back up to an Idera R1Soft / ServerBackup system in the US.

One of our servers absolutely refuses to compile the kernel module. Has anybody else seen this issue? Our server host has exhausted all their ideas, the backup service provider doesn't want to help as it isn't their server that we're backing up.

This is what we get:

```
root@web2 [~]# serverbackup-setup --get-module
Checking if module needs updated
Checking for binary module
Waiting                       |
No binary module found
Gathering kernel information
Gathering kernel information complete.
Creating kernel headers package
Checking '/lib/modules/2.6.32.61/source/' for kernel headers
Found headers in '/lib/modules/2.6.32.61/source/'
Compressing...
uploading kernel package                                                                                        99%   21MB   1.5MB/s   00:00 ETA
Starting module build...
Building                      |          kernel module installer failed. (0):
Internal error encountered. Please contact support
Request ID: (cae5953a-9993-4431-ba94-a91bd22f4644)
http://www.r1soft.com/distros/index.php?uuid=cae5953a-9993-4431-ba94-a91bd22f4644


root@web2 [~]# uname -a
Linux [redacted] 2.6.32.61 #3 SMP Sun Oct 13 20:19:23 BST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Has anybody seen this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's up with the odd kernel version? Can you at least tell us what Linux distribution and version you're using?

Comment: Hey, good question. Our host has tried an array of different kernel versions. This one happens to match another server that works fine (though its 32bit on the working server). The OS is Centos 6.4.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?   Recommend removing all kernel headers, installing new kernel from official sources, then installing matching kernel headers.  Reboot the server and then try to build. We have seen some issues with linking in kernel header trees but that does not seem to be the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the kernel version here is pretty odd - `2.6.32.61`... So it looks like a hand-compiled vanilla kernel. If you don't have a specific reason for doing this, you should probably be on a kernel sourced through the RHEL/CentOS ecosystem, or at least deployed via RPM.

The hotcopy/serverbackup/cdp driver module leverages your running kernel source to collect the headers, *scp* them to an Idera/R1Soft build server, compile on the build server, then ship an appropriate compiled module back to your system. It's an odd process, but that's how they protect their intellectual property.

Go ahead and contact Idera for support. As what they're missing. If you're using an RPM-based distribution, this process usually wants the `kernel-headers` package installed.